# React - JSX conditional tags

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a `Todo` component. My `ToDoContainer` downloads all the todos using fetch. The response looks like the following:

```
[
    { id: 0, checked: 1, text: "bla bla" },
    { id: 1, checked: 0, text: "bla bla 2" }
]
```

After successfully getting my todos, I'm passing them down from `TodoContainer` to `Todo` component which renders them.

Unfortunately I can't make it work:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    { this.props.text }
</li>
```

**How do I pass the info about the checkbox being checked or not?**

I've tried:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" {this.props.checked ? 'not', 'working') />
    { this.props.text }
</li>
```

But it looks like you can't use `{}` within tags in JSX?

The [official guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) isn't helpful either, because doing something like:

```
render() {
    let todoInput = null;
    if (this.props.checked) {
        todoInput = '<input type="checkbox" checked />';
    }
    else {
        todoInput = '<input type="checkbox"/>';
    }

    return (
        <li>
            { todoInput } { this.props.text }
        </li>
    );
}
```

Won't work as it just renders the HTML (not the input itself) and I do not want to create new component just for that or to dangerously set HTML.

Any hints? :(

Comment: `checked={this.state.xxxx}` https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035230/how-to-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-dom-element/40036048#40036048

Comment: How do you pass your response from `ToDoContainer` to `Todo`?

Comment: @Ric for the love of God, now I can't uncheck my checkboxes even with onChange functions.

Comment: I've put together an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q9zwwc?file=index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.checked} />
```

---

OR

Remove single quotes

From :

```
todoInput = '<input type="checkbox" checked />';
```

Like this :

```
todoInput = <input type="checkbox" checked />;
```

---

OR

Conditional tags :

```
this.props.checked ? <CompA /> : <CompB />;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, but can't I do it any other way? Like IF in `jsx` itself? Instead of `foo ? 'bar' : 'bar2'` we have there like extra 5 lines of code. In HTML checked=1 & checked=0 and checked=anything is always checked AFAIK.

Comment: Yes you can just remove single quotes if its element and it will work.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work as expected. Once I set 'checked' I can never uncheck the input. onChange handlers doesn't work as well.

Comment: @VivekDoshi it was an example i put together. hope it help